# Erlang Pattern matching with aliases

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

is there a possibility to match in a function definition do some subset of a touple and still get get complete touple in the method ?

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
myfun({ foo, Bar }: Var) -> otherfunction(Var, stuff).
```

instead of:

```
myfun({ foo, Bar }) -> otherfunction({ foo, Bar }, stuff).
```

I hope this is clear enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? It's not really clear to me...

Comment: Well, I should probably retract it, you did answer it for me, the  = Var part was what I was looking for. 
In hindsight, RTFM would have been the correct answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can ignore some parameters by putting an underscore in front. E.g.

`myfun( {foo, _Bar, Var } )`

will match by ignoring the _Bar parameter.  Is that what you had in mind?

Or did you mean:

`myfun( {foo, Bar} = Var ) -> otherfun( Var ).`

in this case, *Var* will be used in *otherfun* iff the match with *myfun* succeeded. The reason is:  *Var* is un-bound at the time of evaluation of the expression and thus will be assigned to *{foo, Bar}*.

Comment: "ignoring the _Bar parameter" is not strictly correct. The variable _Bar will be bound to the second element of the tuple and can be used as any normal variable. As the _Bar starts with an _ the compiler will not warn about it not being used. Apart from this _Bar behaves as a normal variable and can be used as one.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is what you meant:

```
myfun({foo, Bar } = Var) ->
  otherfunction(Var, stuff).
```

In this way, you can export your function as myfun/1 (one parameter). It will match just on tuples with two elements. The first one must be the "foo" atom, while the second can be anything. You will get a function clause in all other cases, unless you specify different clauses for the function. For example, it would make sense to have:

```
myfun({foo, Bar } = Var) ->
  otherfunction(Var, stuff);
myfun(Var) ->
  {error, bad_format}.
```

I'm not completely sure this is what you're asking, though. Please, let me know if this helped.

Answer (score -3):

If I have this correct, what you want is to have `Var` to be set, containing only a touple matching `{ foo, Bar }` without having to do any additional checks, for conciseness sake.
As far as I've ever seen, you can't do this in Erlang. Sorry. :)

Comment: This is incorrect. As the two other posts indicate you can indeed do what he is asking.